# Roots of a specific high-degree polynomial

Tags: polynomials, numerical-methods, roots

I have the following equation:

$$\left(k_1+k_2\cos\left(\frac n M \frac \pi 2 \right)u^n+k_3\cos\left(\frac m M \frac \pi 2 \right)u^m\right)^2+\left(k_2\sin\left(\frac n M \frac \pi 2 \right)u^n+k_3\sin\left(\frac m M \frac \pi 2\right)u^m\right)^2 \\ =(u^{2M}+1)^2$$

where $n,m<2M$. I want to find the (positive real) roots of this polynomial.

After expansion we got the following polynomial of $u$:

$$ A_{4M}u^{4M}+A_{2M}u^{2M}+A_{2n}u^{2n}+A_{2m}u^{2m}+A_{n+m}u^{n+m}+A_{n}u^{n}+A_{m}u^{m}+A_{0}=0$$

where the coefficients:
$$A_{4M}=1, A_{2M}=2, A_{2n}=-k_2^2, A_{2m}=-k_3^2, A_{n+m}=-2k_2 k_3 \cos(\frac{n-m}{M}\frac{\pi}{2})$$
$$A_n=-2k_1 k_2 \cos(\frac{n}{M}\frac{\pi}{2}), A_m=-2k_1 k_3\cos(\frac{m}{M} \frac{\pi}{2}),A_0=1-k_1^2$$

It obviously can be solved numerically, but I have to find the roots for a lot of different values of the parameters and for great values of $M$ (up to some thousand).

Is there any analytical or numerical consideration which can be used to reduce the computational cost in this specific case or in general?

Comment: You say that $A_{4M},$ $A_{2m},$ $A_{n+m},$ etc., are equal to certain things, but nothing called $A_{4M},$ $A_{2m},$ $A_{n+m},$ etc. is found in your original equation. How are we to understand that?

Comment: Sorry, I will correct that.

Comment: You have a Pythagorean triple, $$(u^{2M}-1)^2 + (2u^M)^2 = (u^{2M}+1)^2\\(2u^M)^2 +(u^{2M}-1)^2 = (u^{2M}+1)^2$$ It might help to equate terms and see what happens.